# Escape double quotes of HTML attributes output by PHP

Tags: php, html, regex, bbedit

Often when writing PHP I'll have it output some HTML like this -

```
echo "<a href="../" title="link title">".$link_text."</a>";
```

Obviously this won't parse as I need to escape the double quotes in the attributes of the `<a>` element. Is there a regex that would quickly do this rather than me manually adding the backslashes?

One other thing - the regex shouldn't escape double quotes outside of the tag (e.g. where I've appended the `$link_text` variable.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should just use single-quotes instead:

```
echo '<a href="../" title="link title">' . $link_text . '</a>';
```

Comment: I disagree with htmlspecialchars inline when printing, by the time you print all arguments should already be clean.

Comment: anyway, @joebert, htmlspecialchars must be used before printing :)

Comment: Thanks - looks like switching to single quotes is the simple (and possibly fastest?) solution. Also - appreciate the concern about cleaning output using htmlspecialchars(). I left it out of the example code for clarity.

Comment: yes, most likely the single quotes method would be the fastest

Comment: in addition, you can use "," instead of "." with echo. this will avoid string concatenation and will be even faster (works only with echo)

Comment: "I left it out of the example code for clarity" -- please don't do this! It causes bad practises by newbies who just copy and paste code from examples.

Answer (score 8):

Solutions I can come up with (not without escaping):

- Single quotes

  ```
  echo '<a href="../">' . $link_text. '</a>';
  ```
- Use double quotes

  ```
  echo "<a href='../'>$link_text</a>";
  ```
- Sprintf

  ```
  echo sprintf('<a href="../">%s</a>', $link_text);
  ```
- Use HEREDOC

  ```
  echo <<<EOF
  <a href="../">$link_text</a>
  EOF;
  ```
- Use template engine like [smarty](http://smarty.net)
- Exit *PHP-mode*:

  ```
  ?><a href="../"><?php echo $link_text ?></a><?php // other code...
  ```

BTW, be sure to use `htmlspecialchars()` on `$link_text` variable, or you’ll have a XSS security hole.

Comment: Thanks - looks like switching to single quotes is the simple (and possibly fastest?) solution. Also - appreciate the concern about the cleaning output using htmlspecialchars(). I left it out of the example code for clarity.

Answer (score 5):

Use (This syntax dont worry about quotes etc)

```
echo <<<EOT
<a href="../" title="link title">$link_text</a>
EOT;
```

Comment: I think that the outer quotes are not meant to appear there.

Answer (score 3):

I'd strongly suggest using templating instead of trying to build strings.

In raw PHP:

```
<a href="../" title="link title"><?php echo $link_text; ?></a>
```

Comment: Point taken - though there's times when I just want to quickly output a small string of HTML (from say a function or method) and using a templating engine is a bit overkill.

Answer (score 0):

use single quotes or use [heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc). I'd prefer the last.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use

```
http://www.example.com/.../Learning-Tutorials/ACTIVE-USER-ACCOUNT/verify.php?email='.$email.'&hash='.$hash.'

"<a href="//www.example.com/.../Learning-Tutorials/ACTIVE-USER-ACCOUNT/verify.php?email="$email&hash=$hash>Click Here to Active</a>"
```

try it.