# Echoing a form object with ' and " in them

Tags: php

I have a problem where I am trying to output a checkbox on an html page the only problem is I want to use a variable that is in $row['STUDENT_ID'] but the checkbox also has double quotes, which is what I am using for echo. The double and single quotes are confusing me and I can't get it to work quite right.

```
     echo "
  <tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="name" value=". $row['STUDENT_ID'] . " />
  <td>" . $row['STUDENT_ID'] . "</td>
  <td>" . $row['FName'] . "</td>
  <td>" . $row['LName'] . " </td>
  </tr>
  ";
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Escape double quotes of HTML attributes output by PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097135/escape-double-quotes-of-html-attributes-output-by-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In such cases use a [HEREDOC](http://php.net/heredoc) string instead:

```
echo <<<HTML
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="name" value="{$row['STUDENT_ID']}" />
    <td>{$row['STUDENT_ID']}</td>
    <td>{$row['FName']}</td>
    <td>{$row['LName']}</td>
  </tr>
HTML;
```

Also notice the `{$..}` curly string syntax for embedding the `$row[]` values.

Answer (score 0):

Read in to [PHP Strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) and check out he examples on how to place double quotes within a set of double quotes (or singles within a set of singles).

```
echo "This is an \"Escaped\" set of quotes";
echo 'Likewise, but \'single\' quote style';
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't echo html, just do it like this:

```
  <tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="name" value="<?php echo $row['STUDENT_ID'] ?>" />
  <td><?php echo  $row['STUDENT_ID'] ?></td>
  <td><?php echo  $row['FName'] ?></td>
  <td><?php echo  $row['LName'] ?></td>
  </tr>
```

If you really want to, then use `\` to escape.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `\` to escape quotes

[check this out](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php7p7.html)