# Add HTML tag to the value stored in php variable not as echo

Tags: php, html

I am building a simple php mail form and it has two different type of message style for sender and receiver each.

I do not just want to escape double quotes. Even i use something like `<h2>` or `<strong>` tags, it does not work.

```
$message1 = "Message 1";
$message2 = "Message 2";

mail($recipient, $subject, $message2, $mailheader) ;
mail($email, $subject2, $message2, $headers2) ;
```

Here I want to add some simple html style for Message 1 and Message 2

I tried

```
$message1 = "'<div style="color:#ff0000">' Message 1 '</div>'";
$message2 = "'<div style="color:#ff0000">' Message 2 '</div>'";
```

But it doesnt work.
How can i achieve this?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#example-3929

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Escape double quotes of HTML attributes output by PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097135/escape-double-quotes-of-html-attributes-output-by-php)

Comment: you need to escape the double quotes like this $message1 = "<div style=\"color:#ff0000\"> Message 1 </div>";
$message2 = "<div style=\"color:#ff0000\"> Message 2 </div>";  @Shebas khan

Comment: output is like this <div style="#ff0000;"> Message 1 </div> It just removes the code but text color doesnt  change

Comment: it is not valid style   style="#ff0000;" you missed color:

Comment: I tried different colors but the result is same

Comment: i said you missed the word *color:*

Comment: I used this <div style=\"color:#ff0000;\">

Comment: can you show your mail header

Comment: $mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
$headers2 = "From:" . $recipient;
mail($recipient, $subject, $message1, $mailheader) ;
mail($email, $subject2, $message2, $headers2) ;

Comment: change your header like this $emailheader ='From:'.$email. "\r\n" .
                'Reply-To: '.$email. "\r\n" .
                'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion() . "\r\n" .
                'Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1'."\r\n".
                'MIME-Version: 1.0'."\r\n\r\n"; @ShebasKhan

Comment: Thank u so much, it worked

Comment: i posted the comment as answer . mark it with green tick it's useful for future user reference @ShebasKhan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to change your header like this

```
$emailheader ='From:'.$email. "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: '.$email. "\r\n" . 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion() . "\r\n" . 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1'."\r\n". 'MIME-Version: 1.0'."\r\n\r\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like this,

```
$message1 = '';
$message1 .= '<div style="color:#ff0000">';
$message1 .= 'Message 1';
$message1 .= '</div>';

echo $messag1;
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot add double quote inside double quotes

```
$message1 = '<div style="color:#ff0000"> Message 1 </div>';
$message2 = '<div style="color:#ff0000"> Message 2 </div>';
```

Comment: *you cannot add double quote inside double quotes*  i added $message1 = "<div style=\"color:#ff0000\"> Message 1 </div>";

Answer (score 0):

```
$message1 = '<div style="color:#ff0000">'.' Message 1 '.'</div>';
$message2 = '<div style="color:#ff0000">'.' Message 2 '.'</div>';
```

You may try this

Answer (score 0):

you can escape double quotes by adding slashes before it:

```
$message1 = "<div style=\"color:#ff0000\"> Message 1 </div>";
$message2 = "<div style=\"color:#ff0000\"> Message 2 </div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$email = 'to-mail@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Subject';

$message = "";
$message .= "<div style='color:#ff0000'> Message 1 </div>";
$message .= "<div style='color:#ff0000'> Message 2 </div>";

mail($email,$subject,$message);
```

OR

Use [Klaviyo Email Template](https://www.klaviyo.com/email-templates) to create attractive Email Template Designs.